# How can I change the color of confirmation button (forgot password option) on email?

Tags: magento2, email-templates, link, password-recovery, confirmation

How can I change the color of confirmation button (forgot password option) on email?

I tried from css, but I think it doesn't support. I'm trying to find where is the main .less file for this.

Answer (score 0):

I found this. There is all about email styling.
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/templates/template-email.html#email-styles